# Doubts about isotrophy and homogeneity of space

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, symmetry

From the following [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/396891/366605), we note that space is isotropic if everything (force, amount of things, separation by distance, e.t.c) is the same in every direction. To call a space isotropic, it shouldn't matter where I stand, wherever I stand, either here or there, **as long as I'm within the space**, everything must be the same in every direction from here or there.

**Question 1:** This kind of makes me think that if space is isotropic, then it must be homogeneous because if not, then isotropic space definition is vague to me and we're giving advantage to some points within the space over others. But I somehow should be wrong, because then space being isotropic always means space being homogeneous, which I don't think is right.

**Question 2:** when we consider a space and think whether it's isotropic or not, and we start looking in every direction whether it looks the same or not, do we only look within the boundaries ? space could be a sphere of 100m diameter and we could say: "hey let's start looking around in every direction and check whether it looks the same" - in that case, do we only look till 50m from us (considering we're at a centre)?

What's your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 3):

For a  connected space, isotropic for *all observers* implies homogeneous, but not vice versa. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropic_manifold

Answer (score 2):

On question one, a homogenous space has no preferred position. That doesn’t rule out a preferred direction (a vector) or a tensor alignment.

The former would occur if there were a universal constant uniform magnetic field. All points are equivalent,  but magnetic dipoles have a preferred direction in which to point.

Whether a uniform electric field would count as homogenous is debatable, since the potential would be position dependent….but potential is not gauge invariant, so does it matter?

The latter would occur if space were a birefringent crystal.  Light with an electric field aligned with the axis would move faster. This is a tensor alignment, as the sign of the aligned field doesn’t matter.

Currently, the only understood nonzero thing is space is the Higgs field, which is a Lorentz scalar: its value is unaffected by rotations, translations, or boosts. Dark energy is still in the not understood category.

Comment: well, then am I misunderstanding isotropic definition ? imagine a sphere in an empty volume and we wanna know if this sphere is isotropic. Some say that it's isotropic around center, because from center, everything is and looks the same. but if you stand on any other point within the sphere, it's not the same. So you can say that sphere is isotropic around center, but we consider sphere and empty volume outside of it as a space and in that case, is this space isotropic ? around center yes, but not for any other points. In that case, what do you say ? is our space isotropic or not ?

Comment: @GiorgiLagidze A sphere would be isotropic to an observer at the center but anisotropic to any other observer.

Comment: The sphere case confuses vectors and affine points. Vectors don’t have an origin, so if all vectors are zero: you are isotopic. Affine points define an origin, and then other points are related to that by a vector.

Answer (score 2):

space is not really isotropic. if you look from earth to our sun, or from Venus you have different looks. So "isotropic is not in the real meaning as you describe it. It just means where ever you stand in some direction you will have as many galaxies  spaced out  than in another direction. and if you travel to a distant galaxy you expect the same.
If you sir on earth way out in our galaxy your view is different from somebody near the center.